# How to merge all records to 2 records and remove all uncombined records?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I use following code to combine(using comma) input records which have same Symptom_Type. The problem is now I can combine and insert records into DB, but how to remove those uncombined records from "nPG_Chemical.NPG_Chemical_Symptoms"?
[image]

```
var SymptomType = nPG_Chemical.NPG_Chemical_Symptoms.GroupBy(Type => Type.Symptom_Type);
foreach (var type in SymptomType)
{
    var text = String.Join(", ", type.Select(x => x.Symptom_Text.ToString()).ToArray());
    nPG_Chemical.NPG_Chemical_Symptoms.Add(new NPG_Chemical_Symptom
    {
        Symptom_Type = type.Key.ToString(),
        Symptom_Text = text
    });

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: What you mean by "uncombined" records?

Comment: @ArghyaC Does not have ",".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your requirement correctly. It seems like all you want is

> After you have combined records by Symptom_Type, and inserted them into database, you want to delete the original records.

If that's what you want, you can do this

```
db.YourTable
    .RemoveRange(db.YourTable
                    .Where(x => !x.Symptom_Text.Contains(",")));
```

Comment: NPG_Chemical_Symptoms is ICollection

Comment: You run it with your db context, with the same logic.

Comment: Yes, I tried to change it into                 db.NPG_Chemical_Symptom.RemoveRange(db.NPG_Chemical_Symptom.Where(x => !x.Symptom_Text.Contains(",")));
but if I only have one record for one type, then there will be no ",". I don't want to remove them also.

Comment: Okay. Then depending on your table schema, there might be different solutions. For example, [1] if your table has auto-increment id, then you can store the last id before adding combined results. Then delete all records with id <= storedId. Or, [2] get the records from db and store locally -> delete all from table -> combine data locally with your logic -> insert them to database.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe it's not a good way, but it works just as what I want.

Comment: Yeah, it is just a quick dirty solution. It has problems like [1] where you have just one record for a type, it'll unnecessarily delete and re-insert [2] If you program encounters some error/exception in between, you might loose original data!

Answer (score 0):

For each base record find all records where base.Symptom_Type contains Symptom_Type from currently verifying record.